# Calculate the total amount of pages of a vBulletin threadin realtime

Tags: mysql, paging, vbulletin

How can the total number of pages of a VB thread be calculated in real time using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CEIL((COUNT(p.postid)) / 10) AS TotalPages
FROM post p 
WHERE p.threadId = @threadId
AND p.visible = 1;
```

This generates the total amount of pages number for all visible posts with 10 replys per page (VBulletin default) in realtime. But for performance reasons I don't use this query any more. Instead, we can use the `replycount` property:

```
SELECT CEIL(t.replycount / 10) AS TotalPages
FROM thread t
WHERE t.threadId = @threadId;
```

There are also related `hiddencount` and `deletedcount` properties that can help if similar calculations should be done for e.g. moderators (which should be avoided for link generation because it changes pagination for users/mods).